Orbit Design Tools/Software
Could you propose some Orbit Design tool or software?
I expect it to give me an optimum orbit for a given criteria and limitations. For example, an orbit with maximum access over an specific point with its semi major axis less than 20000 km and inclination > 40.
max access duration over (lat, long) = (20, 100) subject to a < 20000km & i > 40

what does "maximum access duration" mean exactly? What if orbit A can stay visible for a longer uninterrupted stretch than orbit B, but, on average, B is more often visible?
